# When this fails, why does it delete just one row? (PDO, PHP, and MySQL glitch with types)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

There was a bug in an old project where only one row was being deleted where it should have deleted multiple rows because of an IN statement in the SQL.

I used the following query for PDO:

`DELETE FROM messages_to_people where (receiverID=:receiverID AND messageID IN ($inStatementSubQ))`

each of these parameters are just ids such as 123, 456, 789. For example, var_dump() on the messageIDArray is

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1040' (length=4)
  1 => string '1041' (length=4)
  2 => string '1042' (length=4)
```

The `$inStatementSubQ` is a string generated with various parameters to bind later with the help of a foreach loop that loops through binding the parameters:

```
foreach($messageIDArray as $key=>$id){
    $paramToBind = ":id".$key;
     $foo = $stmt->bindParam($paramToBind, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}
```

If there were, say, 3 rows that should be deleted, this consistently only deleted one of the three rows each time it was run. Then it occurred to me to add  `intval()` on the IDs to make them ints. After that it worked as expected.

```
     $foo = $stmt->bindParam($paramToBind, intval($id), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I'm curious, *before the intval()* why this works to *delete just one row*, PDO reports true each time it binds, and the statements execution returns true as well. I would have expected it to fail, or perhaps to succeed while deleting all with the receiver ID, but I did not expect its old behavior where it deleted one each loop.

Any insights would help me in life,

thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to present some sample data.  var_dump the $messageIDArray.

Comment: Your problem would be much easier to debug had you created your statement that it deletes one row and only one row. Since it's a prepared statement, you would just have to supply next row to delete and you can wrap everything with a transaction - then you'd have no issues debugging this since you'd be able to pinpoint exactly which parameter doesn't let you do what you want to. Suggestion: rewrite the query, don't use `IN`, retry and see if it helps you pinpoint the reason.

Comment: Is the receiver id matching with all rows?

Answer (score 0):

The `intval()` was just a red herring. Though using `intval()` in the actual call to `bindParam()` worked, that's not the core issue. I realized this when I tried `$newInt = intval(id)` and it repeated the behavior of deleting *just one* instead of all of them.

The second parameter of `bindParam()` is mixed &$variable and binds by reference. So bindParam was taking the last ID and using that, ignoring the others. By substituting with

```
    //$stmt->bindParam(":id".$key, intval($id), PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id".$key, $id);
```

I get the behavior I would expect and it deletes all of them.

Answer (score -1):

Problem is that you are passing a string of comma separated ids, rather than passing 3 separate ids. At a guess MySQL with pdo tried to convert that string to an integer, probably just giving you the first id.

In effect you tried to execute

```
DELETE FROM messages_to_people 
where (receiverID=1
AND messageID IN ('1,2,3'))
```

which has been converted to:-

```
DELETE FROM messages_to_people 
where (receiverID=1
AND messageID IN (1))
```

while what you wanted was:-

```
DELETE FROM messages_to_people 
where (receiverID=1
AND messageID IN (1,2,3))
```

You need to change your code to have one parameter for pdo for each id, and pass a value for each one. Not a single parameter for all of them which is a comma separated string.